# How many ways can we pick 3 letters from the word "connection"?

Tags: combinatorics

For no confusion pick means the order doesn't matter and a letter gets removed after choosing it.
i tried to scale this problem to a smaller one for example picking 3 letters from the word "ABBCA".

I tried this method where i compute different cases for example:

case 1: 0A2B: $\binom{1}{1}$=1 which is BBC

case 2: 1A1B: $\binom{1}{1}$ = 1 which is ABC

case 3: 2A0B: $\binom{1}{1}$ = 1 // AAC

case 4: 2A1B: $\binom{1}{0}$ = 1 // AAB

case 5: 2B1A: $\binom{1}{0}$ = 1 // BBA

the combination above is how many letters other then A and B do i take so in this cases its C

i think this is an acceptable method of solving but its very tedious if there are a lot of letters so is there a better way to do it?

Comment: After you picked a letter, do you remove it? Also, your notation is not clear.

Comment: Do you know generating functions ?

Comment: @JoMo yes they do

Comment: @Bulbasaur No didn't get to that point yet

Comment: @RafikBouloudene i recommend you to make reseach about it , your problem can be easily solve by generating functions

Comment: @Bulbasaur alright, so other then that there isn't another practical method?

Comment: For clarity, there is only one way picking "cnc" or three (or more) ways?

Comment: @RafikBouloudene it is the most practical method

Comment: If I understand your problem correctly, solution can be following. There is $\binom{6}{3}$ ways to pick 3 different letters, there is $3\cdot 5$ ways to pick two identical letters and one different letter, there is $1$ way to pick three identical letters. Total number is 36.

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu i didn't understand your question, do you mean how many times can we pick the letter C?

Comment: @RafikBouloudene We can pick first c, then first n, then second c. Or we can pick second c then first c then third n. Are these ways counted as one or not?

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu yes they are counted as one i said the order doesn't matter and the C are identical it doesn't matter if you pick the first one or the second, but you can't pick the second and then pick the second again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**connection**

two **c**'s, two **o**'s, three **n**'s, one **e**, one **i**, one **t**

$(1+x+x^2)(1+x+x^2)(1+x+x^2+x^3)(1+x)(1+x)(1+x)$

Expand this and look at the coefficient of $x^3$.  That will be the number of combinations of three letters possible (order irrelevant, same letters treated as identical)

$$1+6x+18x^2+\color{blue}{36}x^3+53x^4+\dots+6x^9+x^{10}$$

The answer is $36$.

The idea of how this works is effectively the same as brute force.  We break into cases based on how many $c$'s were used, then breaking into further subcases based on how many $o$'s were used and so on, keeping track of how many ways we arrived at certain letter-counts as we go.  If doing this by hand, we could have ignored those values which exceeded $x^3$ as they are irrelevant to us to save on arithmetic.  That said, with computer assistance keeping track of all and expanding the polynomial was a trivial task so there was no need for such a simplification.

For the ABBCA example it is the same: $(1+x+x^2)(1+x+x^2)(1+x) = 1+3x+5x^2+\color{blue}{5}x^3+3x^4+x^5$, there being $5$ different three-letter combinations possible to take from this.

Answer (score 1):

There is $\binom{6}{3}$ ways to pick 3 different letters, there is $3\cdot 5$ ways to pick two identical letters and one different letter, there is $1$ way to pick three identical letters. Total number is 36.

Comment: i understood this solution thanks , i just have one more question if the order did matter would i simply multiply the first result by 3! and the second by 3!/2! and the last one by 1?

Comment: If you mean the order of letters in output three letters combination, then your approach is correct.